# How to call Javascript function when PartialView is loaded in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function InitMap(data) {
        var map = new T.Map();
        var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
        //more code which renders the map
    }
</script>

//partial view razor 
@model System.Data.DataTable

@{
    string strEvents = "[";
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
    {
        strEvents += "[" + row["Lat"].ToString() + ", " + row["Long"].ToString() + ", " + "\"" +
        row["Name"].ToString() + row["Case"].ToString() + "\"" + "],";
    }
    strEvents = strEvents.Remove(strEvents.LastIndexOf(","));
    strEvents += "]";        
}

//here i now need the code to call the above JS function InitMap passing in the JSON string 'strEvents' which renders the map.  

<div id="map" class="map"</div>
```

My question is: When this partial view is loaded, I want the map to be rendered straight away. Above I construct the JSON string using the model in razor. I then want to call the JS function on the same page above passing in the string and rendering the map. I do not know how to do this in razor ?? hope it is as clear as possible.

Comment: How do you load/render the partial view?

Comment: The partial view is loaded by: "@Html.Partial("MapPartial", Model)" from inside the controller view.